# Vertices behaving like parented bone is rotating when neighbouring bones rotate

Tags: armature, vertex-weights

e.g. When I rotate the character's upper shin bone, the vertices behave as if her lower thigh bone is also rotating.
[image]

The vertices around the lower thigh are not weighted to anything else but the thigh bones and I only have one armature modifier. I'm fairly certain it's reacting to that unmoving lower thigh bone but just don't know why.
I don't even know what to google for this problem!
[image]
[image]
I have used many many bone constraints on this rig but as far as I can tell no constraint should result in a mesh deformation without the bone actually moving.
Does Blender just become glitchy when you use too many bone constraints?

[edit] I also want to add that this problem is absent when I import the model and animation into Unreal Engine 4 so it's looking more and more like a bug or a Blender feature that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I actually dont see much of a problem there. (usually you want the knee to stretch instead of just clasping in on its self.) However, try unchecking preserve bone volume.

Comment: The problem is the bulge on the front of the thigh that only appears when the knee bends. The bones that are moving have no weights touching that part of the leg so it shouldn't be moving. Preserve volume also has no effect on the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Consider showing images in [weight paint] mode for the bones you believe are defectively affecting the mesh.

Comment: I could only post two out of the three pictures I had due to being new. Should I just post the weight paint pic as an answer?

Comment: Okay I just edited the question's second picture. Should be more helpful but now you'll just have to take my word for it when I say that those vertices around the lower thigh are not weighted towards anything but the thigh bones and the little bit of the shin you can see.

Comment: Did you check all other bones? including the second bone in the lower leg "I can see you have 2 bones there" and the foot bone? Try selecting one of the vertices in that area in Edit Mode and check the Properties panel to make sure that it's only assigned to the related bone.

Comment: I had a picture showing it before but in edit mode, it shows that most of the vertices being wrongly moved are assigned to nothing but the lower thigh and a little bit from the upper thigh which both are not moving.
The weights are fine, I've checked over and over again.
The deformation in the lower thigh area goes away only if I turn of deform for the lower thigh bone.

Comment: From options, enable showing zero weights which paints zero weight black instead of blue. Verify that its 0 where you need it to be 0. But I'm more concerned about that "preserve volume" you have enabled, have you tried disabling it?

Comment: I know this question is long past relevant to anyone, and there's no file to confirm, but given that the problems are absent in UE, I'd suspect it's due to bendy bones.  Using bendy bones, the rotation of the lower leg can affect the upper leg.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I fixed it, I think. I just dissolved the lower thigh bone and subdivided the upper one and gave the new one the same name as the old lower thigh bone so the weights would sync up.

I still have no idea what the problem was but it's gone now.

Comment: An *answer* should give the root cause.

Comment: Weights. Try to set Show Zero Weights = Active instead of None (in options tab of the weight paint mode). I can bet, you'll be surprised. :-)
The cure - using Clean button of weight tools with low threshold, and then normalize all the deforming groups. Or select and remove verts from groups by hand in edit mode.